# if $f_n(x)=\exp\left\{f_{n-1}(x)\right\}$ for all natural ns and $f_0(x)=x$ find the derivative of $f_n(x)$

Tags: functions, derivatives

if $f_n(x)=\exp\left\{f_{n-1}(x)\right\}$ for all natural ns and $f_0(x)=x$ find the derivative of $f_n(x)$

My attempt:

$$f_n(x)=\exp\left\{f_{n-1}(x)\right\}$$

so we have on applying the chain rule:
$$f'_n(x) = \exp\left\{f_{n-1}(x)\right\}f'_{n-1}(x)$$

but $$f'_{n-1}(x)=\exp\left\{f_{n-2}(x)\right\}f'_{n-2}(x)$$
and so on

but
$$\exp\left\{f_{n-a}(x)\right\}=f_{n-a}(x)$$

so the derivative is $f_n(x)f_{n-1}(x)....f_1(x)$. However my book says that as well as this $$ f_n(x)=\frac{d(f_{n-1})(x)}{dx}$$

I'm not sure how the second result is true. I'd appreciate some inputs

Comment: Are you sure it says $ f_n(x)=\frac{d(f_{n-1})(x)}{dx}$? Actually, $ f_n(x)=f_n'(x)/f_{n-1}'(x)$.

Comment: yes, I'm sure it says that

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$f'_n(x)= f_n(x) f_{n-1}'(x)$$
So by simple induction on $n$ :  $$f_n'(x)=\left(\prod^{n}_{i=1} f_i(x)\right)f'_0(x).$$
But $f_0'=1$ So the closed formula you're looking for is $$f'_n(x)= \prod^{n}_{i=1} f_i(x).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at that doubtful formula when $n = 1$. We know
$$
f_0(x) = x
$$
so
$$
f_1(x) = \exp(x)
$$
The formula claims that

$$ f_n(x)=\frac{d(f_{n-1})(x)}{dx}$$
which, applied when $n = 1$, would say that
$$
f_1(x) = \frac{d(f_0)(x)}{dx}
$$
i.e.
$$
\exp(x) = \frac{dx}{dx} = 1
$$
which is evidently false. So that last claim is just plain wrong. Indeed, it's hard to me to think of something close to it that **is** true.